# Disable org-log-refile note on Capture

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have `org-log-refile` set to `'note` which works great when moving tasks around. However, when I'm capturing, I'd like this behavior disabled.

I tried the following with `org-capture-mode-hook`, `org-capture-after-finalize-hook`, `org-capture-before-finalize-hook`, and `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook` to no avail.

```
;; Record time and note when a task is refiled
(setq org-log-refile 'note)
;; Disable when refiled from org-capture
(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                   (setq-local org-log-refile nil)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work as intended:

```
;; Disable when refiled from org-capture
(define-advice org-capture-refile (:around (oldfunc &rest args) org-disable-log-refile)
  "Set `org-log-refile' to nil while capturing."
  (let ((org-log-refile nil))
    (apply oldfunc args)))
```

Comment: That is indeed the best solution IMO.